# Allowing users to update teir information using forms

Tags: contacts, custom-fields, profile

I am trying to allow registered members to add their own information to their profile after logging in using shortcodes, WordPress and the latest civicm.
Although the page will allow this it doesn't actually update their fields and leaves them blank

Comment: Is your profile set up with 'Standalone Form or Directory' and if so what mode are you using in your shortcode?

Comment: yes the profile is set up with standalone form or directory, and the short code I am using is [civicrm component="profile" gid="29" mode="edit" hijack="1"]. Although it allows users to enter the information, it doesn't save it to their record. As a charity we have limited funds, and so I'm trying to lean this as I go on, but there are some things that we can't do. if this is one of them, I would be happy to ask for a worthy volunteer to come on board and help us with it.

Comment: Great. Might be worth just just checking then in the 'Advanced Settings' in the profile that 'Update the matching contact' is selected for the 'What to do upon duplicate match'?

Comment: That didn't work as the field was already selected.